# Extending GenericModel for Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework

I need to add some logic to GenericModel by means of extending it, but I understand that Play uses generics to enhance the GenericModel. What would be the right and most convenient way to extend this class?

I tried to do this, but some of the methods in GenericModel simply throw a UnsupportedOperationException exception, so this is clearly enhanced somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this working by means of reflection. Everything is now working 100%. :) Not really the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `db.jpa.Model` which also extends `GenericModel`.

If you intend to extends the GenericModel, I would do it in the models package. No need for an external module and it is best to avoid touching playframework core. You will have trouble updating it if you do.

But still, after a quick look at [the source code](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/db/jpa/GenericModel.java), it seems that you are trying to modify [JPA related code.](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) What kind of logic are you talking about?

Comment: The logic being added is basically dealing with adding custom delete cascade rules that are not supported by the DB. So for each entity, you can call .deleteCascade(id) and the foreign references will update to the given id. I don't want to have to copy and paste this functionality into all my entities.

Comment: Looking at Model extending GenericModel, this works perfectly, coz it doesn't call any methods in GenericModel that throws the UnsupportedOperationException.